# Linux Mint 14 window manager is broken

Tags: linux, linux-mint, window-manager

Suddenly since yesterday my window manager is broken, I can't:

- Resize my windows
- Move my windows
- Switch applications (Alt-Tab)
- Change focus to other windows (Current window is always on top, I have to close it to open a new window.)
- Can't use Enter to go into folder
- Can't use backspace to go back
- Find my main menu
- Find the taskbars

And borders are gone too. The reason I believe is because something weird is happening in the window manager, but I couldn't figure out why. Everything was working perfectly until yesterday. I made two new installations yesterday:

- Emacs 24
- Chromium source code setup (Installed the necessary dependencies mentioned in depot-tools. there are actually lot of packages.)

Check out the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you check error messages?

Comment: Linux Mint ships with either MATE or Cinnamon as the default desktop environment. Which one are you using? If you're using mate, what happens if you use the command `marco --replace`?

Comment: @dotVezz make that an answer.

Comment: @jlliagre As much as I would love to, I think it's still only a troubleshooting step - not a full answer. It may be a solution situationally, but probably doesn't address the root problem.

Comment: @dotVezz I have this same problem.  marco --replace brought back my window frames and gadgets for a few seconds, but then they disappeared again.